# How to resolve : javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable [BonitaSoft]

Tags: java, xml, web-services, dom, bonita

I'm trying to create a task in BonitaSoft and connect it to a webService created using Spring Boot I finished all the steps and when i want to test my web service i get this Error : 
[image]

I can see that the Web service is running or consumed here : 
[image]

So the problem is when i want to get the result, ... here is the code where I parse the XML to get the result :

[image]

if you need any additional information please feel free to ask

Comment: Did you test your connector by running the process? This warning message tell you that when the Studio test the execution of the connector it will not be able to deal with connector output that are not Serializable. If you add one or several Groovy script(s) to process the connector output(s) they will not be used when testing the connector in the Studio. Your only option to actually verify that you get the expected output is to run the whole process (or run the connector outside the Studio but that would require to add some stubs for Bonita Engine execution context).

Comment: Thank you so much it's work (y)

Comment: @AntoineMottier please do you have an idea if i want to restart the process automatically if the web Service return false 
well I have an instantiation form which is an authentication form so after submitting email and pwd from the form to the service and the service get the result then if it's true we pass to the next task (I did this) but if it's return False i want to come back to the instantiation form thats what i couldn't do it

Comment: this is a different question so I recommend to create a separated one in order to avoid polluting this thread. Thanks.

Comment: @AntoineMottier yeah i created a new question here is the link if could help me on it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406353/how-to-restart-the-process-if-the-result-of-the-web-service-is-false-bonitasoft    thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning message tell you that when the Studio test the execution of the connector it will not be able to deal with connector output that are not Serializable.

If you add one or several Groovy script(s) to process the connector output(s) they will not be used when testing the connector in the Studio.

Your only option to actually verify that you get the expected output is to run the whole process (or run the connector outside the Studio but that would require to add some stubs for Bonita Engine execution context).