# How to restart the process if the result of the web service is false [BonitaSoft]

Tags: business-process-management, bonita

I have a process of Authentication which contain an instantiation form and a task connected to a web service which search for the username and tha password in the database and return 1 if it's exist and 0 if not.
as you can see in the picture I could do this :
if it's return 1 we pass to the step1 else we end the process
[image]

what I want is if the web Service return 0 the process should be restarted automatically and come back to to the instantiation form !!

Comment: In order to access to Bonita Portal (and so to access Bonita forms) a user need to be authenticated. Default authentication mechanism use Bonita users database to check username and password. Can you clarify why you need a second authentication as part of your process? Maybe tuning the default Bonita authentication configuration might answer your needs.

Comment: I didn't knew that thank you helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access to Bonita Portal (and so to access Bonita forms) and Bonita Engine APIs a user need to be authenticated.

Default authentication mechanism use Bonita users database to check username and password.

Maybe tuning the default Bonita authentication configuration might answer your needs. Authentication process is fully [documented](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/user-authentication-overview) in Bonita official documentation.